# JavaScript remove characters from a string between two characters

Tags: javascript, string

I want to turn this:

```
Celadon (location: Celadon - Indianapolis, IN)
```

into this:

```
Celadon - Indianapolis, IN
```

I cannot simply remove the characters I dont want because this is one of many items in a json array that are like this so I need a way to remove the characters from the "(" to the space right before the "-" and then remove the ")" at the end from every item in the array. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A regex

```
var str = 'Celadon (location: Celadon - Indianapolis, IN)';
var res = str.replace(/(\((.*?)\s+(?=-)|\))/g, '');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/w9cHe/2/)